# Java error compilation while using checked exception

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

I'm using Eclipse, it give me a compilation error when i use this Code

> Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never
> thrown from the try statement body

```
public void f() {
    try {
        System.out.println("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

but when i use Exception instead of IOException it compile, both are checked exceptions, waht am i doing wrong

Comment: It may be that `RuntimeException` (an unchecked exception) is a subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: If above is the exact code you have written, then `System.out.println("");` is never going to throw IOException and that's the reason you are getting compile time error.

Comment: @VinitMore the question was why it worked for some checked exception, i got the answer, it worked because Exception is a cheked exception that may have subException that are uncheked like RuntimeException, and unchecked exception doesnt requiere to catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catch (Exception e)` is a special case in the Java Language Specification. The [rule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) is

> It is a compile-time error if a `catch` clause can catch checked exception class `E1` and it is not the case that the `try` block corresponding to the `catch` clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of `E1`, unless `E1` is `Exception` or a superclass of `Exception`.

`catch (IOException e)` can only catch `IOException` and its subclasses, which are *all* checked exceptions.

On the other hand, `catch (Exception e)` can catch `RuntimeException` and its subclasses (among other things), which are *not* checked exceptions. Therefore, it cannot be concluded that the `catch` block will never be executed.

Comment: the only class that's checked and may have unchecked subclass is EXception right ? does this behaviour works only with Exception ?

Comment: @DEV As the quote says, it also works with any superclass of `Exception`, so `catch (Throwable e)` is also fine. Other than that, I don't think there is anything else.